# MQ Explorer: Need to understand the field JMS_IBM_MQMD_ACCOUNTING TOKEN

Tags: java, jms, mule, ibm-mq, mq

I am using IBM MQ explorer to browse messages on my remote queues. I need to understand the data that comes in the Accounting Token field when I browse in MQ explorer. I see the below data

```
00000   1A 0F D5 C4 F7 F1 C3 C8--C9 D5 F1 C5 F8 C6 F0 C1  |..XXXXCHIN1E8F0A|
00010   C5 F0 00 1E 8F 0A E0 00--00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |E0.±.\.........|
```

I am aware that 00000 and 00010 is the line number. The rest is Hex value but I do not understand the value between |XXXXCHIN1E| This value has remote queue manager name.

When I try to retrieve this value in my mule flow I only get byte[] which when I convert to Hex it is the same as above. Can someone please help me understand the value between the ||?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a user defined one... Read the docs here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q097420_.htm?lang=en

Your 32nd byte seems to be "MQACTT_UNKNOWN"

Comment: So is the HEX code same as the value between ||. I converted it to HEX and did not find it to be the same. How do I retrieve this value between ||? From Accounting Token I am able to get the bytes and convert to HEX but I cannot get value between ||?

Comment: You have both a hex and a character dump listed above. The left hand side is the hex bytes, 16 bytes per line, 2 lines (32 == size of acct token), and the bit between the |..| part is the ascii/ebcdic equivalent of the hex chars - usually converted based on the codepage of the message or something like that. You can see from the hex, that the data is in ebcdic not in ascii, so the originator of the accounting token is usually either mainframe or IBM i (iSeries / OS400).